# Header Text not going to bottom of code

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML Code:

```
<body>

<img id="logo" src="logo.png">
<br>

<!-- Start: Page Buttons -->

<div align="center" id="buttonBar">

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Home</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Author</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Literature</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Projects</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Pictures</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">How To...</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Updater</a>
</div>

<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Copyright</a>
</div>

</div>
<!-- End: Page Buttons -->

<h2>Welcome</h2>

</body>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
#buttonBar{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
z-index=1;
padding-top: 65px;
}
.menuButton{
height: 50px;
width: 125px;
background-color: lightblue;
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
margin-left: 5px;
border-radius: 10px;
}

.menuButtonText{
font-size: 25px;
text-align: center;
line-height: 50px;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

#logo{
padding-top: 15px;
padding-left: 15px;
}
```

The `h2` I have in my HTML, will for some reason go under the logo(`img`) but is staying above the div's. How do I get my H2, and for anything else I put, under the Div's?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle link: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djqkct1g/)

Comment: You have your buttons fixed from the top of the page which removes them from the flow of the document. And a side note, `z-index=1` isn't valid syntax.

Comment: Your "position: fixed" is causing the buttonbar to lock to the top of the page.

Comment: @Arbel - How does that move the h2 below the divs?

Comment: I need the H2 to go underneath the Div's. This just puts the H2 next to the img

Comment: What are you trying to achieve a fixed header maybe?

Comment: @j08691 you are right, probably read too fast.

Comment: @Mikey through the `position: fixed;` I am trying to create a menu bar that will stay on the screen even when the user will scroll down.

Comment: @jazzy1331 Take a look at this: http://sixrevisions.com/css/fixed-navigation-bar/

Comment: @Mikey The only difference between what is on the site and what I have is the `<nav>` tag. So it isn't really helping in fixing the problem I have with the `h2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created you a fiddle to solve your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vwqk411e/2

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul> 
</nav>
<div id="container">
    <h2>Hello</h2>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
       margin-top: 100px;
    }

    nav {
        width: 100%;
        position:fixed;
        border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color:#fff;
    }

    ul {
        width: auto;

    }

    li {
        display:inline-block;
        float:left;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 3px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
```

Comment: small modification: add background: #fff; to nav.  Otherwise, the back ground is transparent and the text can be seen as it scrolls by nav.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found out that <nav> is new in HTML 5, so its good to use the latest tags

Comment: @jazzy1331 You're welcome. It is good to use the latest mark up conventions.

Answer (score 1):

Change the beginning markup to this:

```
<div align="center" id="buttonBar">
<div style="text-align: left; padding:0 0 15px 15px; vetical-align: top;"><img id="logo" src="logo.png"><br></div>
<div class="menuButton" >
<a href="link" class="menuButtonText">Home</a>
</div>
```

Modify your css to this:

```
#buttonBar{
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left; 0;
background: #fff;
}
```

You can pull the inline styling I made into the css, and adjust the padding for the image to your specification.

Comment: I need the position to be fixed, can't be relative

Comment: You are not going to get the results you expect with that markup.

Comment: I have tested it, and I am getting the results I expected originally.

Comment: I put <div>abcd</div> underneath the h2 element 1000 times.  You expect the text to scroll beside the buttons?  The image is also going to scroll up, as well.